# Jquery - need help on numberformatting for amounts

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use the [numberformatter plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/numberformatter) for jQuery.

It works, but I don't get the right format... I looked at the documentation, but I'm struggling.

I think there is no BE for the Belgium format in the international list.

I tried and played below code and played with # and 0.

```
$('input[name$=txtTotal]').blur(function () { $(this).format({ format: " #.###,00", locale:"be" }); });
$('input[name$=txtTotal]').blur(function () { $(this).format({ format: " #.###,00"}); });
```

This is what I want:  a comma for decimals separator and a dot for thousand separator and 2 decimals after comma.

input 420000  should be shown 42.000,00
input 1234,56      should be shown 1.234,56
input 123456,78  should be shown 123.456,78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('input[name$=txtTotal]').blur(function () { $(this).format({ format: "#,###.00", locale:"de" }); })
```

In the documentation, ',' always means separator and '.' always means decimal separator.  The 'de' local should plug in the appropriate values.

Comment: thanks so much, it works... I also learnt the , and . meaning.. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the "de" locale. It looks like you should get the same output

Comment: no it's not. I've tried with/without formatter...123,45 gives me 12340.00 etc... please advice?